# Illustrator: Shortcut for switching documents

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in Illustrator (CC 2017) to switch between opened documents?

Comment: mac or PC? And has it changed from the older versions?

Comment: `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts....` → `Menu commands (dropdown)` → `Other misc → Navigate....`

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much every Adobe app that I've used, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> switches between documents.

No idea why some are trying to overcomplicate this, when the shortcut is built-in already.

Answer (score 3):

For windows PC press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `TAB` to go backwards through the tabs

Answer (score 2):

Should vary a bit on MAC but on Windows it will be this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> will switch to the next open document. I would add that if you have 3 or more open documents, you can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to switch back the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a French (Canadian) keyboard on a Mac, it’s <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>À</kbd>. Probably the same on French (France) keyboard?